# Massive difference in execution time between computers with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some code that takes a csv file and draws a graph out of it.

It is a bit lengthy so I am posting the source here: https://pastebin.com/y7fQf57K

In short, it loads a csv file into a pandas dataframe, then builds a few extra columns that will be used for the display and calls the display code.

the display code is this:

```
plt.style.use('default')
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(4, figsize=(20, 10), sharex='all',
                                         gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [4, 1, 1, 1]},
                                         constrained_layout=True)
 
# handle the cycle background color
cycles_range = df.reset_index().groupby('cycle')['index'].agg(['min', 'max'])
for i in cycles_range.index:
    start = df['timestamp'][cycles_range['min'][i]]
    end = df['timestamp'][cycles_range['max'][i]]
    color1 = "navajowhite"
    color2 = "orange"
    ax1.axvspan(start, end, facecolor=color1 if i % 2 == 0 else color2, alpha=0.5, zorder=-1)
    ax2.axvspan(start, end, facecolor=color1 if i % 2 == 0 else color2, alpha=0.5, zorder=-1)
    ax3.axvspan(start, end, facecolor=color1 if i % 2 == 0 else color2, alpha=0.5, zorder=-1)
    ax4.axvspan(start, end, facecolor=color1 if i % 2 == 0 else color2, alpha=0.5, zorder=-1)
 
# subplot 1 - price
ax1.plot(df['timestamp'], df['price'], color='midnightblue', alpha=0.6, zorder=0)
ax1.plot(df['timestamp'], df['break_even_long'], color='limegreen', linewidth=2, zorder=1)
ax1.plot(df['timestamp'], df['break_even_short'], color='crimson', linewidth=2, zorder=1)
ax1.plot(df['timestamp'], df['break_even_hedge'], color='fuchsia', linewidth=2, zorder=1)
ax1.set_ylabel('price USDT')
ax1.margins(x=0)
 
# subplot 2 - volume
ax2.plot(df['timestamp'], df['volume_up'], color='limegreen', zorder=0)
ax2.plot(df['timestamp'], df['volume_down'], color='crimson', zorder=0)
ax2.set_ylabel('volume')
ax2.margins(x=0)
ax2.set_ylim(0)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter())
 
# subplot 3 - profit
ax3.fill_between(df['timestamp'], 0, df['profit'], color='forestgreen', alpha=0.5, zorder=0)
ax3.fill_between(df['timestamp'], 0, df['fee_paid'], color='red', alpha=0.8, zorder=1)
ax3.set_ylabel('equity USDT')
ax3.margins(x=0)
ax3.set_ylim(0)
ax3.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter())
 
# subplot 4 - our volume
ax4.fill_between(df['timestamp'], 0, df['volume_traded'], color='indigo', alpha=0.5, zorder=0)
ax4.set_ylabel('volume traded')
ax4.margins(x=0)
ax4.set_ylim(0)
ax4.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter())
 
# set the ticks
hours = mdates.HourLocator(interval=1)
h_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(h_fmt)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
 
# align the labels
fig.align_ylabels([ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4])
 
# display the graph
plt.show()
```

On my laptop (MBP 2019), it takes about 4-5 seconds to execute and show the graph.
On one of my colleague's 3 years old macbook (slower cpu, only 8gb ram) it takes over 2 minutes.

Obviously my computer is not 25x faster than his.

But then on a 2-3 years old Window desktop PC, it takes over 2 minutes as well.

The data source is about 120k lines and with a smaller data source, it does shrink proportionally.

What is interesting is that the time spent is after the viewer opens, so my script is already executed at that time.

Is there anything in the way I draw the graph that could cause some massive performance drop on some architectures?

Comment: Can you try commenting out different plotting commands and see if you can identify which one(s) are critical to the time difference between the machines?

Comment: yes, I will try that, but I can't until tomorrow. Also, I tried the default backend ang pyQt5 as well, same result.

Comment: It may be informative to try with the `agg` backend (and `savefig` instead of `show`) and see whether there is still a difference or not.

Comment: I have sent several versions and we'll see what comes out

Comment: Can the downvoter comment why?